# How can I move imports to parent component in Vue.js and Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am making a project using `Vue.js` with `Nuxt.js`.

I have a child component like this:

`pages/some-page/index.vue`

```js
<template>
    <content-root>
        <!-- other components -->
    </content-root>
</template>

<script>
    import ContentRoot from '~/components/content-root'
    import Component1 from '~/components/component1'
    import Component2 from '~/components/component2'
    import Component3 from '~/components/component3'
    export default {
        layout: 'content',
        components: {
            ContentRoot,
            Component1,
            Component2,
            Component3
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to change it like this:

`pages/some-page/index.vue`

```js
<script>
    import ContentRoot from '~/components/content-root'
    export default {
        layout: 'content',
        components: {
            ContentRoot
        }
    }
</script>
```

and move the imports to its parent component:

`components/content-root.vue`

```js
<script>
    import Component1 from '~/components/component1'
    import Component2 from '~/components/component2'
    import Component3 from '~/components/component3'
    export default {
        layout: 'content',
        components: {
            Component1,
            Component2,
            Component3
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I move the imports to the parent component?

Comment: You can use `slot`.